# Copia de una pagina a multiples paginas y creando dichas paginas usando macros en base a un criterio de busqueda

Tags: excel, vba, macros, vb, excel-2013

Buen Dia,

Mi Duda es la siguiente, de momento recibo un reporte en Excel, cuya primera pagina tiene un nombre X (El nombre cambia).

Esta pagina tiene X cantidad de Filas, en la primera columna siempre tendra un numero de ID, este se veria de la Siguiente Manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco es que de acuerdo a esa ID (en la imagen PO#) separe cada ID (PO#) en paginas del mismo libro de Excel y luego quede en esa nueva pagina la informacion de los otros campos solo para ese ID, por ejemplo el ID: P3005 tiene 3 Filas y su propia pagina tendria que copiar algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento he podido realizar solo el codigo para crear las paginas con los codigos sin embargo no he podido copiar la informacion, el codigo que tengo es:

```
 Function chequear_hoja(sheetName As String) As Boolean

Dim wkb As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set wkb = Sheets(sheetName)
On Error GoTo 0

chequear_hoja = IIf(Not wkb Is Nothing, True, False)
End Function

Sub crear_hojas2()
Dim Lista As Range
Dim iX As Long


On Error GoTo Cancelar

Set Lista = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Señalar rango de la lista", _
Title:="Lista de nombres", Type:=8)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For iX = Lista.Count To 1 Step -1
If chequear_hoja(Lista(iX)) = False Then
Sheets.Add.Name = Lista(iX)
End If
Next iX

Sheets("Hoja1").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Cancelar:
End Sub
```

De ser posible me gustaria que el pegado ya llevara el formato de los encabezados (Letra Arial, Tamaño 12, Negrita, Fondo Amarillo) y que todo lo pegedo vaya con Borde.

Agradecere cualquier ayuda, pues he encontrado tutoriales sin embargo hasta el momento no he podido realizarlo.

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Todos tus datos están en la primera página. Yo creo que es más fácil ir duplicando esa página, 1 vez por cada PO#, y en cada una de ellas borra lo que no sea de ese PO#. Aplica el formato deseado a la primera página, y al irla duplicando ya se duplica con ese formato, así no tienes que estar dando formato a cada nueva copia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lo he testeado, pero esto debería servirte:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DistribuirDatos()

    Dim Ids As New Scripting.Dictionary 'Necesitas la librería Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim C As Range
    Dim Key As Variant

    AhorroMemoria True 'desactivamos ciertas funciones para hacerlo todo más rápido

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'cambia esto

    With wb.Sheets(1) 'se refiere siempre a la primera página
        'Hacemos un bucle para almacenar todos los Id únicos en el diccionario
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'última fila en la columna A
        For Each C In .Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
            If Not Ids.Exists(C.Value) Then Ids.Add C.Value, 1
        Next C
    End With

    'Hacemos un bucle por cada Key que haya en el diccionario para pasar los datos a otra hoja
    For Each Key In Ids.Keys
        MoverDatos wb, CStr(Key)
        Formatos wb
    Next Key

    AhorroMemoria False 'reactivamos las funciones para que todo vuelva a la normalidad

End Sub
Sub MoverDatos(wb As Workbook, Key As String)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Col As Long, LastRow As Long

    Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)) 'añadimos una hoja nueva

    ws.Name = Key 'ponemos el ID como nombre de la hoja

    With wb.Sheets(1)
        Col = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'calculamos la última columna
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Key 'filtramos los datos para mostrar sólo el ID actual
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'calculamos la última fila tras el filtro
        .Range("B1", .Cells(LastRow, Col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Range("A1")  'copiamos los datos a la nueva hoja desde la columna B
        .AutoFilterMode = False 'quitamos el filtro
    End With

End Sub
Sub Formatos(wb As Workbook)

    Dim Col As Long

    With wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        Col = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(1, Col))
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Font.Size = 12
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End With

End Sub
Sub AhorroMemoria(isOn As Boolean)

    Application.Calculation = IIf(isOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.EnableEvents = Not (isOn)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not (isOn)
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Si te ha servido @ReneAlas, por favor no olvides marcarla como correcta.

Comment: Gracia Damian, 

Si me genera las paginas con su nombre y me genera los encabezados por pagina en el formato que se quiere, sin embargo no copia la informacion se muestra solo:

Order Customer Name Style Code Design Code size Quantity

Sin Embargo me hace falta que haga la copia de los contenidos por PO# (id) Es decir la informacion no la trae de la pagina uno

Comment: Qué raro, me podrías subir un archivo con unos cuantos ejemplos de muestra? esta línea: `.Range("B1", .Cells(LastRow, Col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Range("A1")` copia desde la columna B hasta la última que haya y todas las filas visibles (tras filtrar) pegándolas en la A1 y siguientes de la nueva hoja.

Comment: Perdon por la duda, pero como subo archivo aqui en Stack Overflow?

Comment: Subelo a wetransfer o cualquier proveedor gratuito y pones el link en tu pregunta.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18PzIl5vdC7KrSUD1b9IpTNxidZ1rojUB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ahi esta el link

Comment: @ReneAlas ya he visto el fallo, estaba intentando calcular la última fila como se calculan las columnas... Arreglado eso y añadido lo de la negrita que se me pasó, y que las columnas se auto ajusten al contenido. Fíjate que he cambiado la línea de `Set wb = ThisWorkbook` ThisWorkbook se refiere al libro en el que se guarda el código, si no pegas el código en ese libro, cambia eso.

Comment: Excelente muchisimas Gracias por tu ayuda es lo que necesitaba.